# Problem with event listeners not being added again, once React unmounts them

Tags: javascript, reactjs, addeventlistener

I am very new to react, and i decided to build a website using create-react-app for experience. I imported a Gallery component into my code which is causing me some problems. It's basically a Picture Gallery with a filtering and shuffle option which works fine whenever you completely reload the page, yet stops working once you switch between routes (with react-router) inside the webpage itself.

My guess is that the eventListeners are not being added to my buttons once react unmounts them, and I am really unsure as to how to refactor the code at hand, inorder to get it going. I have tried using Hooks but I can't make it work.

How do I refactor the

```
componentDidMount () {
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
      window.demo = new Demo(document.getElementById('grid'));
    });
  }
```

part of the code in order to get it working without having to reload the entire page?

Homebase.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './Homebase.scss';
import Shuffle from 'shufflejs';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import Demo from './Homebasescript.js';

class homebase extends Component {

  componentDidMount () {
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
      window.demo = new Demo(document.getElementById('grid'));
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (

      <section>
      <div className="homebase-page">

      <div className="container-about">
        <div className="row-about">
          <div className="homebase-title-container">
            <h1 className="homebase-about-title">Townhall <span style={{color: 'rgb(21, 115, 209)'}}>12</span> Base Designs</h1>

            <div className="switch-container-th12">
              <button className="switch-buttons-th12 switch-to-th9-12">
                <div className="switch-buttons-text-12">coming soon</div>
              </button>
              <button to="/Townhall-10" className="switch-buttons-th12 switch-to-th10-12">
                <div className="switch-buttons-text-12">Townhall 10</div>
              </button>
              <button to="/Townhall-11" className="switch-buttons-th12 switch-to-th11-12">
                <div className="switch-buttons-text-12">Townhall 11</div>
              </button>
              <button to="/Townhall-12" className="switch-buttons-th12 switch-to-th12-12">
                <div className="switch-buttons-text-12">Townhall 12</div>
              </button>
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div className="container-about">
        <div className="row-about">
          <div className="col-4@sm col-3@md">
            <div className="filters-group filters-group-left">
              <label htmlFor="filters-search-input" className="filter-label filter-color">Search</label>
              <input className="textfield filter__search js-shuffle-search" type="search" id="filters-search-input" />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div className="row-about">
          <div className="col-12@sm filters-group-wrap">
            <div className="filters-group filters-group-right">
              <p className="filter-label filter-color">Filter</p>
              <div className="btn-group filter-options">
                <button className="btn btn--primary" data-group="war">War</button>
                <button className="btn btn--primary" data-group="trophy">Trophy</button>
                <button className="btn btn--primary" data-group="farm">Farm</button>
                <button className="btn btn--primary" data-group="fun">Fun</button>
                <button className="btn btn--primary" data-group="contributors">Contributors</button>
              </div>
            </div>
            <fieldset className="filters-group">
              <legend className="filter-label filter-color">Sort</legend>
              <div className="btn-group sort-options">
                <label className="btn active">
                  <input type="radio" name="sort-value" value="dom" defaultChecked /> Default </label>
                <label className="btn">
                  <input type="radio" name="sort-value" value="title" /> Title </label>
                <label className="btn">
                  <input type="radio" name="sort-value" value="date-created" /> Date Created </label>
              </div>
            </fieldset>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      </div>
      </section>

    );
  };
};

export default homebase;
```

and the other file is
Homebasescript.js

```
import Shuffle from 'shufflejs';

class Demo {
  constructor(element) {
    this.element = element;
    this.shuffle = new Shuffle(element, {
      itemSelector: '.picture-item',
      sizer: element.querySelector('.my-sizer-element'),
    });

    // Log events.
    this.addShuffleEventListeners();
    this._activeFilters = [];
    this.addFilterButtons();
    this.addSorting();
    this.addSearchFilter();
  }

  /**
   * Shuffle uses the CustomEvent constructor to dispatch events. You can listen
   * for them like you normally would (with jQuery for example).
   */
  addShuffleEventListeners() {
    this.shuffle.on(Shuffle.EventType.LAYOUT, (data) => {
      console.log('layout. data:', data);
    });
    this.shuffle.on(Shuffle.EventType.REMOVED, (data) => {
      console.log('removed. data:', data);
    });
  }

  addFilterButtons() {
    const options = document.querySelector('.filter-options');
    if (!options) {
      return;
    }

    const filterButtons = Array.from(options.children);
    const onClick = this._handleFilterClick.bind(this);
    filterButtons.forEach((button) => {
      button.addEventListener('click', onClick, false);
    });
  }

  _handleFilterClick(evt) {
    const btn = evt.currentTarget;
    const isActive = btn.classList.contains('active');
    const btnGroup = btn.getAttribute('data-group');

    this._removeActiveClassFromChildren(btn.parentNode);

    let filterGroup;
    if (isActive) {
      btn.classList.remove('active');
      filterGroup = Shuffle.ALL_ITEMS;
    } else {
      btn.classList.add('active');
      filterGroup = btnGroup;
    }

    this.shuffle.filter(filterGroup);
  }

  _removeActiveClassFromChildren(parent) {
    const { children } = parent;
    for (let i = children.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      children[i].classList.remove('active');
    }
  }

  addSorting() {
    const buttonGroup = document.querySelector('.sort-options');
    if (!buttonGroup) {
      return;
    }
    buttonGroup.addEventListener('change', this._handleSortChange.bind(this));
  }

  _handleSortChange(evt) {
    // Add and remove `active` class from buttons.
    const buttons = Array.from(evt.currentTarget.children);
    buttons.forEach((button) => {
      if (button.querySelector('input').value === evt.target.value) {
        button.classList.add('active');
      } else {
        button.classList.remove('active');
      }
    });

    // Create the sort options to give to Shuffle.
    const { value } = evt.target;
    let options = {};

    function sortByDate(element) {
      return element.getAttribute('data-date-created');
    }

    function sortByTitle(element) {
      return element.getAttribute('data-title').toLowerCase();
    }

    if (value === 'date-created') {
      options = {
        reverse: true,
        by: sortByDate,
      };
    } else if (value === 'title') {
      options = {
        by: sortByTitle,
      };
    }
    this.shuffle.sort(options);
  }

  // Advanced filtering
  addSearchFilter() {
    const searchInput = document.querySelector('.js-shuffle-search');
    if (!searchInput) {
      return;
    }
    searchInput.addEventListener('keyup', this._handleSearchKeyup.bind(this));
  }

  /**
   * Filter the shuffle instance by items with a title that matches the search input.
   * @param {Event} evt Event object.
   */
  _handleSearchKeyup(evt) {
    const searchText = evt.target.value.toLowerCase();
    this.shuffle.filter((element, shuffle) => {
      // If there is a current filter applied, ignore elements that don't match it.
      if (shuffle.group !== Shuffle.ALL_ITEMS) {
        // Get the item's groups.
        const groups = JSON.parse(element.getAttribute('data-groups'));
        const isElementInCurrentGroup = groups.indexOf(shuffle.group) !== -1;
        // Only search elements in the current group
        if (!isElementInCurrentGroup) {
          return false;
        }
      }
      const titleElement = element.querySelector('.picture-item__title');
      const titleText = titleElement.textContent.toLowerCase().trim();
      return titleText.indexOf(searchText) !== -1;
    });
  }
}

export default Demo;
```

I would be extremely thankful for any help, sincei have been stuck on this for days!

Comment: `DOMContentLoaded` has occurred  before any react component mounts.

Comment: You are absolutely right! I thought i could call it repeatedly by having it inside the ```componentDidMount```-function but i was wrong. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @charlietfl said, `DOMContentLoaded` has already occurred on initial page load, and will not be triggered again when you navigate between routes in your SPA.

Try removing the listener:

```
componentDidMount () {
    //document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    //  window.demo = new Demo(document.getElementById('grid'));
    //});

    window.demo = new Demo(document.getElementById('grid'));
}
```

Comment: Oh wow, that is absolutely amazing! It's actually working now, without having to refresh the page anymore! In the beginning i thought that wrapping ```DOMContentLoaded``` inside ```componentDidMount``` would call it again. But you are absolutely right, it only gets called once! I have to admit, i am quite confused, but i will keep on looking into this to fully understand it! Thank you very much for your help!